# Java.lang.classnotfoundexceprtion Com.sun.rowset.cachedrowsetimpl

Tags: android

I am using socket connection to access data from database to my android application and result set is not serialize. So i used cached row set it works fine in normal client server application but when i use it in android application class not found exception occurred. I also added the jre system library to my project but the problems is not solved. I am tired from this problem. Please help me.

Comment: have you import rowset.jar properly with latest version.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must manually include the rowset.jar file in the endorsed or common library directory of your server

```
<jboss-home>/lib/endorsed
<jboss-home>/common/lib
```